# Identification of race condition for complex openMP code

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, race-condition

This block of openMP Code is running fine but I need to ensure that there is no race condition. Therefore, I have made the `j` variable private.

By doing this, I don't think that any race condition should exist for the assignment operation in the most inner loop. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,k) shared (result_buffer,trans_a,element_b)
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
result_buffer[i]=0; 
{   
    for (j = 0; j<(N/comm_size); j++)
    {               
            for(k=0; k<N; k++)
            result_buffer[k]=result_buffer[k]+trans_a[j*N+k]*element_b[j];
    }               
 }
```

Comment: Um... is the first `{` supposed to be *before* the `result_buffer[i]=0;`?

Comment: no..it is inside the most outer 'For' loop.

Comment: If the first for-loop is an outer-loop, then please edit the question to show this. As it is right now, the the first loop is by itself and is the only thing being parallelized.

Comment: Mystical: I know that only the first outer loop is parallelized as #pragma is put on the outermost "for" loop.

I am interested to know whether this piece of code will result in race condition during the "assignment operation" carried out in the inner-most "For" loop with index "k".

Comment: result_buffer[k]=result_buffer[k]+trans_a[j*N+k]*element_b[j];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one problem right now is that your "outer-loop" isn't an outer-loop because you don't have the `{}` in the right place.

So in that sense, no you don't have a race-condition because the `pragma` will only apply to this:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    result_buffer[i]=0;
```

and not the rest of the code. Your other two loops are ***not*** parallelized and therefore no race condition.

---

That aside, if you intended your code to be this:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    result_buffer[i]=0; 

#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,k) shared (result_buffer,trans_a,element_b)
for (j = 0; j<(N/comm_size); j++)
{               
    for(k=0; k<N; k++)
        result_buffer[k]=result_buffer[k]+trans_a[j*N+k]*element_b[j];
}
```

Then yes, you *will* have a race condition.

Your inner loop modifies the entire `result_buffer` array. All iterations of the outer-loop will also clash on the same dataset.
So there will be a race condition.

As it stands right now, the only loop that that's parallelizable is the inner-most loop.

Comment: hey mystical..you just nailed it.